# Standard Normal Distribution Findng A

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution, standard-deviation

I have the following question and i am dumbfounded on how to find the a in my given question.

$$\sigma= 10000$$
$$\mu= 50000 $$
Find the monthly income which is exceeded by 10 % of employees.

I have 
$$ P(X=a) = 0.1$$
$$P(\frac{a-\mu/}{\sigma}) = 0.1$$

I am stuck at this part.

Comment: You have left out part of the question. Are the given of mean, standard deviation for monthly income?

Comment: Unless these guys are making a lot more than I am, maybe the given mean and SD are for _annual_ salaries. In R, `qnorm(.9, 50000, 10000)` returns 62,815.52 (annual) and `qnorm(.9, 50000/12, 10000/12)` returns 5234.63 (monthly). If you are using normal tables, you will get slightly less accurate numbers because of the rounding required to use tables. Hope you can see how these results match your results from the method in the Answer.

Answer (score 1):

Look up $\Phi^{-1}(0.9)$ in the tables and you see $1.2816$ so this equals $\frac{a-\mu}{\sigma}$